# Need help interpreting question- display text area when form submitted, but form has no onSubmit

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help interpreting what this employer is looking for!  I'm applying for a job and they asked me to do some coding exercises in codepen (which I've never used before).  They want me to "Hide the thank you message until the form has been submitted"

However, the form in their example has no submit action.  If you click the submit button in codepen you get an error message / broken link.  My original thought was just to have an onClick function display the thank you message when the submit button is pressed, regardless of whether the form actually submits...but I'm confused because the last question had me write an onClick function, so I feel like they must want something different.  Should I write some code to handle the form somehow??  How would you handle this?

Thank you!

I completed step 1, and am trying to do step 2...

```js
function toggle(value) {
  if (value == 'show') {
    document.getElementById('reviewText').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('reviewText').style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function showThanks {
  document.getElementById('thanks').style.display = 'block';
}

$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

```css
#reviewText {
  display: none;
}

#thanks {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label>Would you like to us leave a review? </label>
  <div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio" name="review" value="Yes" onClick="toggle('show')"/>Yes</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio" name="review" value="No" onClick="toggle('hide')"/>No</label>
  </div>
  <!-- Step 1. Hide the review text box unless user selects "Yes" -->
  <div class="textarea" id="reviewText">
    <label>Great! Please leave your review here:</label>
    <br>
    <textarea cols="40" rows="10"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <button name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
<!-- Step 2. Hide the thank you message until the form has been submitted -->
<div id="thanks">Thanks for your feedback! Have a great day.</div>
```

Comment: so bind a submit handler....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the form element has no action attribute defined, the data is processed in the same url the form is displayed ([more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data)). I think in your case you need to define a handler for the submit event of the form, something like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].addEventListener('submit', function () {
  console.log('submitted');
  document.getElementById('thanks').style.display = 'block';
});
```

Comment: Great idea, that makes perfect sense.  Thank you!